# HTTPS ignores Options -indexes

Tags: .htaccess, https

Over a http connection .htaccess Options -indexes works as expected, however over https the rule is being ignored.

How can I make connections over http a obey Options -indexes?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would be your .htaccess file is probably not being read for `https` vhost. `Typically` there is a separate VirtualHost for `443`. Make sure it has `AllowOverride All` set for it as well in the Apache config file.

Or as you have done, you can put it in the global `httpd.conf` and it will cover all sites.

Answer (score 0):

httpd.conf has been set to Options -indexes

This fixed the problem